# Does $\int^1_0\frac{(1-s)^\alpha}{s^\beta} \operatorname d \!s$ converge?

Tags: calculus, special-functions

I want to ask about the finitess of the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int^1_0\frac{(1-s)^\alpha}{s^\beta}ds
\end{equation}

when $\alpha>\beta>1$. This integral is very similar to the Beta function, aside from the negative power $-\beta$ here. Can anyone confirm if there really exists some big $\alpha$ such that the integral is finite? Thank you.

Comment: For $\beta \geqslant 1$, you have a non-integrable singularity at $0$. $(1-s)^\alpha$ is essentially $1$ there, so you are left with $$\int_0^\varepsilon \frac{ds}{s^\beta}.$$

Comment: Check $\beta$ function.

Comment: @canis89: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is finite if and only if
$$\beta<1\quad\text{and}\quad -\alpha<1\iff \beta<1\quad\text{and}\quad \alpha>-1$$

Comment: You're right, thank you. It's too much to hope for that this is finite.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Nice work, Sami, as usual!